# Cannot read property 'getSymbolByModule' of undefined

Tags: angular, angular-cli

[Error in Cannot read property 'getSymbolByModule' of undefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFo5p.png)

Answer (score 3):

First remove folder **node_modules**

```
rm -Rf node_modules/
```

then edit your **package.json** file: change "**@angular/compiler-cli**" to the latest version (as of today:  "^4.1.2")

and reinstall your packages:

```
npm update -D && npm update -S
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved the same issue following indications found in [angular-cli issue 5940](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5940)